# Add PFX to strong name CSP on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have created **VSTO Addin project** which is *signed* using a *Password* *protected* **PFX** certificate and added the project to **VSTS**,

Now while building I get an error as failed to import certificate, to fix that I need to import PFX certificate, so as suggested on different SO posts and microsoft support, I am trying to import certificate using **sn** tool as follows,

I had created an .cmd(bat) file which has following commands,

> C:
>
> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\
>
> sn -i "%1\Sixmod5PFX\Sixmod5Certificate.pfx" VS_KEY_BD774ABB8BB29878

and added **Run batch script** task to build definition before **MSBuild** step,
but as we know when we run this command on local machine, it prompts for a password which user can enter,

Same thing happens on VSTS and fails, as it don't get password.
Is there any way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a private build agent (e.g. Deploy an agent on Windows), then install PFX certificate manually on that agent machine (as run the command on local machine and specify password in prompt window)

Comment: facing an Issue, whenever I restart my windows VM (the one, here private build agent is set up) I need delete PFX certificate and add it back again, though with same Id it was added earlier.